# Сборка Lua под Windows

Tags: lua

Подскажите пожалуйста, как собрать статическую либу из исходников Lua 5.4 ?

В исходниках есть Makefile-файл, но как его использовать ? В чем его использовать ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)#Makefile

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, есть для винды файл exe (вроде на оф сайте).

Во-вторых, для использования make-файла в UNIX-системах нужен make, далее make install.